# How to use Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate in QDateTimeEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

In QDateTimeEdit it is possible to set format by string with the `setDisplayFormat(const QString &format)`, but i see no function which receive `Qt::DateFormat` enumeration instead of string.

My goal is to have format of QDateEdit depending on user locale.
Maybe it is possible to fetch string format which is used for Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate in `fromString` and `toString` but i can't find it.

Comment: you mean: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#timeFormat ?

Comment: Looks exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to set display format.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDateTimeEdit w;
    QLocale currentLocale = QLocale::system();
    w.setDisplayFormat( currentLocale.dateFormat( QLocale::ShortFormat ) + " " + currentLocale.timeFormat( QLocale::ShortFormat ) );
    w.setDateTime( QDateTime::currentDateTime() );
    w.show();
    a.exec();
}
```

It look like this in Mac
[image]